# React Native: Best way to pass array of objects to a function in a Component

Tags: react-native

I have a component which has two functions in it. One function returns an array of objects while the other receives it as a parameter. Both the functions being in the same component.

Example Code:

```
export default class Test extends Component {

func1 () {
   return arrayofobj
}

param = this.func1();

func2 (param) {
   param.id
}
}
```

So, my question is. How can we pass and access the array of objects to "func2" i.e. param.id
Also, I do not want to use state or props in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You do not really understand what a class and component are. Try to learn about it here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Thanks @temakozyrev. I question was more from a Angular to React movement perspective. And I found that there was no difference. However, I did go through the documentation as well.